# Why complex template doesn't work?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <complex>
#include<windows.h>
#define PI 3.14159265358979323846
#define A 0.0000000001
using namespace std;
complex<double> dir(0,1);
class Car
{
    directionX=0;
    directionY=1;
    public:
    Car(char *type) 
    {
        fuel=30;
        speed=0;
    }
    void TurnLeft()
    {
        const double angle = 5*PI/180;
        dir = polar(abs(dir), arg(dir) + angle);
        if(abs(dir.real())<A)
        {
            dir.real()=0;
        }
        if(abs(dir.imag())<A)
        {
            dir.imag()=0;
        }
        directionX=dir.real();
        directionY=dir.imag();
    }
    void TurnRight()
    {
        const double angle = 5*PI/180;
        dir = polar(abs(dir), arg(dir) - angle);
        if(abs(dir.real())<A)
        {
            dir.real()=0;
        }
        if(abs(dir.imag())<A)
        {
            dir.imag()=0;
        }
        directionX=dir.real();
        directionY=dir.imag();
    }
};
```

It's a cut out of my project, I'm afraid of posting 456 code lines here.

I had a C++ project to submit and I prepared it in my pc. I had to use complex template and it worked perfectly. But when I wanted to run my code in another pc it showed error in `real()` and `imag()` functions of `complex` class. I don't have any clue why it didn't compile at all.

Comment: May you show us your code please?

Comment: We also don't have a clue. It would help if you create a [mcve]. Maybe you are using different implementations?

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for [`complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) template member functions. You cannot change the value of real part at line:

```
dir.real()=0;
```

Instead of it you should pass new value as an argument:

```
dir.real(0);
```

Same problem at `dir.imag()=0;`

By the way, your code snippet cannot be compiled because `directionX`, `directionY` and several other variables are not declared.